# how to pass a argument with HTTP get method in .net core web api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to build a simple web api using .net core web api which will do basic mathematics operations. I have written controller part which consists of multiple get methods when it is called it returns the value with the operation performed.
controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Calculation.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MathController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("Add")]
        public int Add(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 + value2;
        }
        [HttpGet("Subtract")]
        public int Substract(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 - value2;
        }
        [HttpGet("Multiply")]
        public int Multiply(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 * value2;
        }
        [HttpGet("Division")]
        public int Division(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 / value2;
        }
    }
}
```

so how can I Pass the argument values with the api  so it return the value of mathematical operation. like if I go to https://localhost:44309/api/math/add/{{argument values value1 and value 2 say 25 and 25}} it will return 50
likewise https://localhost:44309/api/math/subtract/{{argument values value1 and value 2 say 25 and 25}} it will return 0

Comment: Standard HTTP methods.  You're using get's, so it would just be https://localhost:44309/api/math/add?value1=25&value2=25

Answer (score 6):

You can pass argument with same url
    `https://localhost:44309/api/math/add?value1=25&value2=25`
or change the route to

```
[HttpGet("Add/{value1}/{value2}")]
```

and then 
    `https://localhost:44309/api/math/add/25/25`

Answer (score 0):

Query string parameters work fine for this job.